# Default push-notification white square before app is loaded

Tags: android, push-notification, icons, phonegap

I've managed to suscessfully setup phonegap-push-plugin on Android - I am able to receive messages from FCM. When I've launched the app and recieve a message my custom icon is displayed in the status bar..Great!

### BUT, when the app has not been launched and a message is recieved the icon defaults back to the white Square.

Plugin:

phonegap-version cli 8.0.0
phonegap-plugin-push v2.1.3

Code used when app has launched:

```
const push =  PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "418827009056", 
        sound: "true",
        vibrate: "true",
        icon: "notification",
        iconColor: "#002060",
        clearBadge : true,
    },
    browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
  });
```

Is there a way in the config.xml to add a default icon for push-notifications but the app has launched?

Comment: There must be same name you mentioned in `icon: "notification"` with android icon name

Comment: Possibly..but how would I set my custom icon in the config.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
<application />
```

as mentioned in FCM android documentation if you not need to send icon name in notification response or there is trouble to get name.

Comment: I never seen this before we can specify notification icon from any other `xml` file!